# Why is Laravel league/ouath2 token for re-login not recognized

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I'm making an app that's using ouath2 login. It works fine when I log in for the first time, but when I try to log in again I get this:Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry.
I've installed league/oauth2/client and called it in my code, but for some reason it's not wokring. I tried everything I could remember, but I don't know what's the problem.
Here are my:
LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\VatsimOAuthController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;

/**
 * This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
 * redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
 * to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
 */
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $provider;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->provider = new VatsimOAuthController;
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (! $request->has('code') || ! $request->has('state')) { // User has clicked "login", redirect to Connect
            $authorizationUrl = $this->provider->getAuthorizationUrl(); // Generates state
            $request->session()->put('vatsimauthstate', $this->provider->getState());
            return redirect()->away($authorizationUrl);
        }
        else if ($request->input('state') !== session()->pull('vatsimauthstate')) { // State mismatch, error
            return redirect('/')->withError("Something went wrong, please try again.");
        }
        else { // Callback (user has just logged in Connect)
            return $this->verifyLogin($request);
        }
    }

    protected function verifyLogin(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $accessToken = $this->provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
                'code' => $request->input('code')
            ]);
        } catch (IdentityProviderException $e) {
            return redirect('/')->withError("Something went wrong, please try again later.");
        }
        $resourceOwner = json_decode(json_encode($this->provider->getResourceOwner($accessToken)->toArray()));

        // Check if user has granted us the data we need
        if (
            ! isset($resourceOwner->data) ||
            ! isset($resourceOwner->data->cid) ||
            $resourceOwner->data->oauth->token_valid !== "true"
        ) {
            return redirect('/')->withError("We need you to grant us all marked permissions");
        }

        $this->completeLogin($resourceOwner, $accessToken);
        return redirect()->intended('/')->withSuccess('Login Successful');
    }

    protected function completeLogin($resourceOwner, $token)
    {
        $account = User::firstOrNew(['id' => $resourceOwner->data->cid]);
        if ($resourceOwner->data->oauth->token_valid === "true") { // User has given us permanent access to data
            $account->access_token = $token->getToken();
            $account->refresh_token = $token->getRefreshToken();
            $account->token_expires = $token->getExpires();
            $account->name=$resourceOwner->data->personal->name_first;
            $account->email=$resourceOwner->data->personal->email;
        }

        $account->save();
        auth()->login($account, true);

        return $account;
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return redirect('/')->withSuccess('You have been successfully logged out');
    }
}
```

VatsimOAuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;

class VatsimOAuthController extends GenericProvider
{
    /**
     * @var GenericProvider
     */
    private $provider;

    /**
     * Initializes the provider variable.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct([
            'clientId'                => config('vatsim_auth.id'),    // The client ID assigned to you by the provider
            'clientSecret'            => config('vatsim_auth.secret'),   // The client password assigned to you by the provider
            'redirectUri'             => route('login'),
            'urlAuthorize'            => config('vatsim_auth.base').'/oauth/authorize',
            'urlAccessToken'          => config('vatsim_auth.base').'/oauth/token',
            'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => config('vatsim_auth.base').'/api/user',
            'scopes'                  => config('vatsim_auth.scopes'),
            'scopeSeparator'          => ' '
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Gets an (updated) user token
     * @param Token $token
     * @return Token
     * @return null
     */
    public static function updateToken($token)
    {
        $controller = new VatsimOAuthController;
        try {
            return $controller->getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
                'refresh_token' => $token->getRefreshToken()
            ]);
        } catch (IdentityProviderException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;
use App\Http\Controllers\VatsimOAuthController;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * Your user model will need to contain at least the following attributes.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'access_token',
        'refresh_token',
        'token_expires',
    ];

    /**
     * At least the following attributes should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'access_token',
        'refresh_token',
        'token_expires',
    ];

    /**
     * When doing $user->token, return a valid access token or null if none exists
     *
     * @return \League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken
     * @return null
     */
    public function getTokenAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->access_token === null) return null;
        else {
            $token = new AccessToken([
                'access_token' => $this->access_token,
                'refresh_token' => $this->refresh_token,
                'expires' => $this->token_expires,
            ]);

            if ($token->hasExpired()) {
                $token = VatsimOAuthController::updateToken($token);
            }

            // Can't put it inside the "if token expired"; $this is null there
            // but anyway Laravel will only update if any changes have been made.
            $this->update([
                'access_token' => ($token) ? $token->getToken() : null,
                'refresh_token' => ($token) ? $token->getRefreshToken() : null,
                'token_expires' => ($token) ? $token->getExpires() : null,
            ]);

            return $token;
        }
    }
}
```